# Is it possible to format cell color directly from the formula line?

Tags: excel

I know how to do this using conditional formatting and VBA, but I was curious if it can be done directly from the formula line.  For example, I have a field in column H that is either **"Valid"** or **"Invalid"**, and based on this would like to color the row red or green(without using conditional formatting/VBA)

I'd like to put something to this effect in another cell to achieve this....

```
If(H2 = "Valid", A2:H2(Color=Green), A2:H2Color=Red))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **It's not possible.**

You need to use either conditional formatting or VBA.